# 1 UIButton two separate Segues

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a UIButton which is controlled by a SegmentedController now my question is: How does one present a popover segue dependant on the outcome of the single button. Basically, I have one Button which is set for either Login or Sign Up. If the user Logs in, then that goes to the Home screen which works fine etc, but when I select the Sign Up option, the button changes to Sign Up and when I click that I would like a popover to be modally presented over the current screen for the user to sign up. my current code allows me to login but when the button is switched to the Sign Up option, I cannot for the life of me work this out and its been twisting my brain for the past 6 hours now. I have read so much about segues and I cannot figure it out.... Your help will be GREATLY APPRECIATED.

[Picture of my code if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHsHg.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code, not a picture of your code. Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through your code to see what it is doing?

Comment: Hi Paulw11,
The picture is a link which you can view by clicking on it. I have solved the problem however using the answer from Simone, if I remove the isSignIn variable out of the signup section then it performs my segue as I wish for it to do. However, should you wish to take a look and let me know if I can improve on this then please do so, I would appreciate your input on the basis that any input is good input regardless of if I change it or not, I like to analyse the views of others and see where I can improve.

Comment: I understood that there was a picture of your code, however you should include actual code *in your question as text* as this makes it easier for people to read as well as cut and paste into an answer if appropriate

Comment: Makes sense, I will do so in the future Paul, thanks for the advice! Im new to this site as I have mostly written code on my own before and not sought any help or advice but as you can imagine, writing code and designing UI over 4 days can get a bit much if you don't have adequate rest in between. Advice taken and definitely next time I post, if I post, I will include code in body of text :) Happy Coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method *LoginAction* you check if the boolean *isSignin* is true or false.
If it is true, you go for the signin process.
If it is not true, you go for the signup process. However, there seems to be an error here because inside the second scope, you check again if the user is signinIn, but the code executes because the user is not signing in, and you ask for another check, which you already performed inside the other scope, which does not pass of course because the *isSignin* variable is false. The correct code should be

```
@IBAction func LoginAction(_ sender:UIButton){ 

   //You check if it s true
   if isSignin {
      //User login
   }
   else {
     //You should not check for the value of isSignin here!
     //User registration
   }
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH Simone, this one simple boolean had me wrapped for 6 hours and I'm guessing this is because I have been working on this project for 7 solid days now and had very little sleep..... Never the less, thank you VERY much for your input!!! I removed the ( if isSignin value) and hey presto it works amazingly now!!!!!

Comment: Glad it helped you @Matt

Answer (score 1):

This is because your segue is attached to your button. To solve this attach the segues to the view controller instead and give them identifiers. Then create an IBAction for your button and perform any checks you need to and the use performSegue using the identifier you set.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment williej926, I appreciate your input but have solved my problems with Simone's answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Created a demo view because your logic seemed correct. I would recommend double checking your if/else statement since you if signUp {...} else { if signUp {..}}

```
@IBAction func pressedTheButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            //go to red view
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "redViewSegue", sender: nil)
        } else {
            //go to green view
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "greenViewSegue", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

[image: viewlayout]

[image: connections]

Comment: Thanks for the input Lunarchaos42, Ideally I was looking to present modally not show them, this way I can create an overlay screen which now works thanks to Simone's answer below!! if I remove the isSignIn variable from the signup process then it works PERFECTLY!!! Thank you anyways for taking the time to do this little mock up. I will keep this in mind for other segues.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you create two *manual segues* in IB, and not *action segues*. Do so by ctrl-dragging from the sender View controller to the destination view controller. Make sure to give them each a unique segue identifier.

Then, create an IBAction for the button and conditionally call either of the segues based on the necessary checks.